# Google Street View API - catch zoom changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have read documentation about Google Street View API and did not find any event handler to catch changing of zoom.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewEvents

> Street View Events
>
> When navigating between Street View or manipulating its orientation,
> you may wish to monitor several events that indicate changes to the
> StreetViewPanorama's state:
>
> **pano_changed** fires whenever the individual pano ID changes. This event does not guarantee that any associated data within the panorama
> (such as the links) has also changed by the time this event is
> triggered; this event only indicates that a pano ID has changed. Note
> that the pano ID (which you can use to reference this panorama) is
> only stable within the current browser session.
>
> **position_changed** fires whenever the underlying (LatLng) position of the panorama changes. Rotating a panorama will not trigger this
> event. Note that you could change a panorama's underlying position
> without changing the associated pano ID, since the API will
> automatically associate the nearest pano ID to the panorama's
> position.
>
> **pov_changed** fires whenever the Street View's StreetViewPov changes. Note that this event may fire while the position, and pano
> ID, remain stable.
>
> **links_changed** fires whenever the Street View's links change. Note that this event may fire asynchronously after a change in the pano ID
> indicated through pano_changed.
>
> **visible_changed** fires whenever the Street View's visibility changes. Note that this event may fire asynchronously after a change
> in the pano ID indicated through pano_changed.

so, I can catch change panoID, position, heading, pitch, but can't find a way to catch changing of zoom. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the zoom_changed event.

[from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanorama) (under "Events"):

> **zoom_changed** | Arguments:  None
>
> This event is fired when the panorama's zoom level changes.

```
panorama.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoomCell = document.getElementById('zoom-cell');
  zoomCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getZoom();
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd13Lmdy/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initPano() {
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('pano'), {
      position: {
        lat: 37.869,
        lng: -122.255
      },
      pov: {
        heading: 270,
        pitch: 0
      },
      visible: true
    });

  panorama.addListener('pano_changed', function() {
    var panoCell = document.getElementById('pano-cell');
    panoCell.innerHTML = panorama.getPano();
  });

  panorama.addListener('links_changed', function() {
    var linksTable = document.getElementById('links_table');
    while (linksTable.hasChildNodes()) {
      linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.lastChild);
    }
    var links = panorama.getLinks();
    for (var i in links) {
      var row = document.createElement('tr');
      linksTable.appendChild(row);
      var labelCell = document.createElement('td');
      labelCell.innerHTML = '<b>Link: ' + i + '</b>';
      var valueCell = document.createElement('td');
      valueCell.innerHTML = links[i].description;
      linksTable.appendChild(labelCell);
      linksTable.appendChild(valueCell);
    }
  });

  panorama.addListener('position_changed', function() {
    var positionCell = document.getElementById('position-cell');
    positionCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPosition() + '';
  });

  panorama.addListener('pov_changed', function() {
    var headingCell = document.getElementById('heading-cell');
    var pitchCell = document.getElementById('pitch-cell');
    headingCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().heading + '';
    pitchCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getPov().pitch + '';
  });

  panorama.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomCell = document.getElementById('zoom-cell');
    zoomCell.firstChild.nodeValue = panorama.getZoom();
  });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initPano);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#pano {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#floating-panel {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  position: static;
  border: 0px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="pano"></div>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Position</b>
      </td>
      <td id="position-cell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>POV Heading</b>
      </td>
      <td id="heading-cell">270</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>POV Pitch</b>
      </td>
      <td id="pitch-cell">0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Zoom</b>
      </td>
      <td id="zoom-cell">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Pano ID</b>
      </td>
      <td id="pano-cell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <table id="links_table"></table>
  </table>
</div>
```